# Perl code to translate nagios status file to old format?

Tags: perl, nagios

On an existing project that uses Nagios V1, we need to upgrade it to Nagios V3.
All is fine except the status file (status.dat) that has changed between the two versions.
There are too many perl scripts using the old status file format to change them. Instead, I would like to write a perl code that convert the status file from new format to the old one :

To simplify the problem (could be considerated as a perl question) :

The input file is something like this :

```
hoststatus {
    key1=val1
    key2=val2
    key3=val3
        }
hoststatus {
    key1=val4
    key2=val5
    key3=val6
        }
servicestatus {
    key11=val11
    key12=val12
    key13=val13
        }
servicestatus {
    key11=val14
    key12=val15
    key13=val16
        }
```

And should be transformed into this file :

```
HOST;val1;val3;val2
HOST;val4;val6;val5
SERVICE;val13;val11;val12
SERVICE;val16;val14;val15

Note the values are written following a chosen keys order. In the above listing :
"key1,key3,key2" for hoststatus blocks
"key13,key11,key12" for servicestatus blocks
```

How can I code that in Perl ?

Comment: What have you tried? You are expected to put forth some effort, write some code, show us what you've done and what you're having problems with. It's unlikely anybody is going to write a solution for you.

Comment: Is that not an helping website ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that each hoststatus & servicestatus blocks always contain only 3 keys-values and that the new order is always 1st,3rd,2nd for HOST and 3rd,1st,2nd for SERVICE

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open (my $IN,'<','status.dat') or die "$!";
my $type;
my @v;
while (<$IN>) {
    chomp;
    if (/(.+)status/) {
        $type=uc $1;
    }
    elsif (/=(.+)/) {
        push @v,$1;
    }
    elsif (/\}/) {
        if ($type eq 'HOST') {
            print join(';',$type,$v[0],$v[2],$v[1]),"\n";
        }
        elsif ($type eq 'SERVICE') {
            print join(';',$type,$v[2],$v[0],$v[1]),"\n";
        }
        undef @v;
    }
}
close $IN;
```

Comment: Thank you ! I am perl total novice, it helps me a lot.